# How to resolve uploading project.apk onto Device Timeout

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am attempting to launch my application but this is what I get. I am using Eclipse with ADD.I am trying to run this project but it seems it cant get uploaded on the virtual device
any suggestions on how I could resolve this ?

```
[2012-10-05 04:44:10 - Android_Test] ------------------------------
[2012-10-05 04:44:10 - Android_Test] Android Launch!
[2012-10-05 04:44:10 - Android_Test] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-05 04:44:10 - Android_Test] Performing com.example.android_test.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-10-05 04:44:10 - Android_Test] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'TestDevice'
[2012-10-05 04:44:10 - Android_Test] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'TestDevice'
[2012-10-05 04:44:12 - Android_Test] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-10-05 04:44:12 - Android_Test] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-10-05 04:45:04 - Android_Test] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-10-05 04:45:04 - Android_Test] Uploading Android_Test.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-10-05 04:45:09 - Android_Test] Failed to install Android_Test.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
[2012-10-05 04:45:09 - Android_Test] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Try closing the virtual device and start again..

Comment: I closed the device by clicking X. Is that how you close it ?

Comment: try adb kill-server and adb start-server then try installing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to > Window menu >Preferences > Android > DDMS > increase value of ADB connection Time out

if this not works then try..

Reset ADB from DDMS > Devices > Reset ADB (down arrow from right corner)

if this fails then you have to restart your AVD

Comment: That did it. Thanks. What is DDMS by the way ?

Comment: you are welcome :) it is debug monitor service which connected with ADB (debug bridge) ultimately with our AVD

Comment: @AdamZedan BTW you can accept answer if it helps to solve your problem :)

Comment: I was going to do that but was waiting on the SO timer. Thanks again